# Query by other entity's id in JPA repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an SQL database with two related tables, `my_entities` and `custom_entities`.
The `my_entities` table has the columns `id`, `custom_entity_id`.

In my Groovy code, both are handled using `Entity` classes:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity  {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "custom_entity_id")
    CustomEntity customEntity

    [...]
}
```

and

```
class CustomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "pooled")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "pooled", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator", parameters = [
            @Parameter(name = "value_column_name", value = "sequence_next_hi_value"),
            @Parameter(name = "prefer_entity_table_as_segment_value", value = "true"),
            @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "pooled"),
            @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "100"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "100")])
    Long id

    [...]
}
```

I have a JPA repository `MyEntityRepository` class for querying the `my_entity` table:

```
@Repository
interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    [...]
}
```

In `MyEntityRepository`, I am trying to implement a `findByCustomEntityIds()` method like this:

```
    @Query("""
           select e
           from MyEntity e
           where e.deleted = false
           and e.customEntity in :ids
            """)
    List<TestCollectionQuery> findByCustomEntityIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids)
```

In MySQL, the query is rather simple (for instance with id `2400`), clearly no joins required:

```
SELECT t.* FROM my_entities t WHERE custom_entity_id in (2400);
```

Apart from the automatic translation from underscores to camel case, the trailing `_id` in the SQL table column name is stripped; otherwise, the code does not compile.

I also have a custom Groovy class which calls that method:

```
class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository

    List<MyEntity> getEntities(List<Long> customEntityIds) {
        return myEntityRepository.findByCustomEntityIds(customEntityIds)
    }
```

The call raises the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [2400] did not match expected type [...CustomEntity (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [2400] did not match expected type [...CustomEntity (n/a)]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [2400] did not match expected type [...CustomEntity (n/a)]
```

From the error message, I understand that the input should be a list of `CustomEntity` objects, instead of IDs (`Long`).

A potential workaround seems to be querying the `custom_entities` table in order to convert the custom entity ids from `Long` to `CustomEntity` objects.
However, that would require adding a JPA `CustomEntityRepository`, and seems very inefficient. It would require an additional database call just for the purpose of converting IDs into objects, so that I can eventually query for the IDs (which I already have had to begin with) in the `my_entities` table.

The reason why I have the IDs for the custom entities, but not the objects, is that they are provided by user input further up the line.

My question is thus: how can I implement a method in the `MyEntityRepository` that implements the MySQL query stated above based on a list of custom entity IDs, without converting them from `Long` into `CustomEntity` objects?

Or is there a more fundamental flaw in my design?

Comment: Your method is named wrong, rename it to `findByCustomEntityIdIn` instead of `findByCustomEntityIds` and remove the `@Query`. Or if you want to keep the query use `and e.customEntity.id in :ids` instead of `and e.customEntity in :ids`.

Comment: I've had to keep the `@Query` because of the additional condition inside, but appending `.id` has solved it indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should end in `"and e.customEntity.id in :ids"` not in `"and e.customEntity in :ids"`.